# is this possible? binary tree doing INSERTION in O(root logn) time

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

is it possible to do insertion in O(√logn) time? I don't believe that it's possible, the closest I can think of is the red black tree way which would be logn. What do y'all think?

Answer (score 3):

You can do insertion into a binary tree in O(1). Here is an example in C++.

```
auto insert(unique_ptr<Node> old_tree, int new_value) {
     return make_unique<Node>(new_value, std::move(old_tree), nullptr);
}
```

The lesson here is:

- Not every tree is binary
- Not every binary tree is a binary search tree
- Not every binary search tree is balanced.

Answer (score 0):

As you can [construct a sorted array by `O(n)` from a binary search tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61072901/3768871), if you could do insersion in
[image]
, you could do the sort in
[image]
(which is not possible for the general comparison based algorithms).